# Ansible: Add public key to bitbucket and checkout the repo

Tags: git, ansible, bitbucket

I'm trying to develop an Ansible script that will checkout a repo from bitbucket to a host.
I have a key, I have a repo and prepared module git in Ansible that will checkout the repo.

If I go to Bitbucket-> settings->ssh key and add the key from the host **manually** then the script will checkout the repo.

```
- name: Download the repository  
  git:
    key_file: /home/{{ device_user }}/.ssh/id_rsa
    repo: '{{ my_repo }}'
    dest: /home/{{ device_user }}/my_repo
    depth: '1'
    force: yes
    accept_hostkey: yes
```

So it's working, so far.

The issue here is how to add **automatically** via Ansible to Bitbucket?
It would be great if Ansible Controller could do that because it already has the key there. But if there are other ways I'm open to them.

I tried community.general.bitbucket_access_key
But it fails on "Failed to retrieve access token..." and there is not too much hints on the internet. I failed to solved this.

Edit:

I installed the module as the documentation says.
On the Bitbucket, workspace settings I created OAuth consumer
name: device and for Account, workspace, projests set to read and for repositories permission reads and admin, as the docs says.

```
- name: Create access key
  community.general.bitbucket_access_key:
    repository: 'my_repo'
    client_id: xxxxxxxxx # Key generated by Bitbucket
    client_secret: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx # Secret generated by Bitbucket
    username: my_name.admin
    key: '{{lookup("file", "/home/{{ device_user }}/.ssh/device.pub") }}'
    label: 'device'
    state: present
```

And the error is following:

```
fatal: [169.254.155.9]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to retrieve access token: {'url': 'https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token', 'status': 400, 'content-security-policy-report-only': \"script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'strict-dynamic' 'unsafe-inline' 'self' http: https: https://d301sr5gafysq2.cloudfront.net; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://aui-cdn.atlassian.com https://d301sr5gafysq2.cloudfront.net; report-uri https://web-security-reports.services.atlassian.com/csp-report/bb-website; default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob: *; connect-src bitbucket.org *.bitbucket.org bb-inf.net *.bb-inf.net id.atlassian.com analytics.atlassian.com as.atlassian.com api-private.stg.atlassian.com api-private.atlassian.com cofs.staging.public.atl-paas.net cofs.prod.public.atl-paas.net intake.opbeat.com api.media.atlassian.com api.segment.io xid.statuspage.io xid.atlassian.com xid.sourcetreeapp.com bam.nr-data.net bam-cell.nr-data.net sentry.io bqlf8qjztdtr.statuspage.io https://d301sr5gafysq2.cloudfront.net; object-src about:; base-uri 'self'\", 'server': 'nginx', 'vary': 'Accept-Language, Cookie', 'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'x-b3-traceid': '05a9d3c28cad6147', 'x-dc-location': 'ash2', 'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload', 'date': 'Mon, 22 Feb 2021 07:02:34 GMT', 'expires': 'Mon, 22 Feb 2021 07:02:34 GMT', 'x-served-by': 'app-3012', 'content-language': 'en', 'x-static-version': 'd4819e0e263d', 'x-render-time': '0.0134270191193', 'connection': 'close', 'x-version': 'd4819e0e263d', 'x-request-count': '2373', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'content-length': '198', 'msg': 'HTTP Error 400: Bad Request', 'body': b'{\"error_description\": \"Cannot use client_credentials with a consumer marked as \\\\\"public\\\\\". Calls for auto generated consumers should use urn:bitbucket:oauth2:jwt instead.\", \"error\": \"invalid_grant\"}'}"}
```

I guess the important message is: **Cannot use client_credentials with a consumer marked as \\"public\\"**.

So I made the consumer private:

And I got following error:

```
fatal: [169.254.155.9]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to retrieve access token: {'url': 'https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token', 'status': 400, 'content-security-policy-report-only': \"script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'strict-dynamic' 'unsafe-inline' 'self' http: https: https://d301sr5gafysq2.cloudfront.net; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://aui-cdn.atlassian.com https://d301sr5gafysq2.cloudfront.net; report-uri https://web-security-reports.services.atlassian.com/csp-report/bb-website; default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob: *; connect-src bitbucket.org *.bitbucket.org bb-inf.net *.bb-inf.net id.atlassian.com analytics.atlassian.com as.atlassian.com api-private.stg.atlassian.com api-private.atlassian.com cofs.staging.public.atl-paas.net cofs.prod.public.atl-paas.net intake.opbeat.com api.media.atlassian.com api.segment.io xid.statuspage.io xid.atlassian.com xid.sourcetreeapp.com bam.nr-data.net bam-cell.nr-data.net sentry.io bqlf8qjztdtr.statuspage.io https://d301sr5gafysq2.cloudfront.net; object-src about:; base-uri 'self'\", 'server': 'nginx', 'vary': 'Accept-Language, Cookie', 'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'x-b3-traceid': '859f3c3a6f0cdf50', 'x-dc-location': 'ash2', 'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload', 'date': 'Mon, 22 Feb 2021 07:11:20 GMT', 'expires': 'Mon, 22 Feb 2021 07:11:20 GMT', 'x-served-by': 'app-3015', 'content-language': 'en', 'x-static-version': 'd4819e0e263d', 'x-render-time': '0.0334351062775', 'connection': 'close', 'x-version': 'd4819e0e263d', 'x-request-count': '3514', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'content-length': '98', 'msg': 'HTTP Error 400: Bad Request', 'body': b'{\"error_description\": \"No callback uri defined for the OAuth client.\", \"error\": \"invalid_request\"}'}"}
```

And here the importatnt message is **No callback uri defined for the OAuth client**.

I know that this could be set in the consumer settings but I failed to solve this.

Comment: Bitbucket has an API: https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/users/%7Bselected_user%7D/ssh-keys#post

Comment: Can you show the code of what you tried with the `community.general.bitbucket_access_key` module? And the full error you get? That would help to find why it's not working. From the message and the code of the module, the problem would be in the OAuth authentication process and there should be more explanation on this in the error message, just after "Failed to retrieve access token: ". Did you correctly provided the client id and secret as documented by the module? (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/bitbucket_access_key_module.html#notes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally get it working.

It was only the settings in the Bitbucket. I figured out that the callback must be set in the way: https://bitbucket.org/my_repo/

So the module community.general.bitbucket_access_key works.